# Unable to use ActiveMQ priority messages using STOMP protocol in nodejs

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, message-queue, stomp

I have an application which sends messages to a queue, and another application which subscribes to the queue and process it. I want OTP messages to be given higher priority than other messages, hence I am trying to use ActiveMQ message priority to achieve this.

This is the code for ActiveMQ connection using STOMP protocol in nodejs using stompit library:

```
const serverPrimary = {
  host: keys.activeMQ.host,
  port: keys.activeMQ.port,
  ssl: ssl,
  connectHeaders: {
    host: '/',
    login: keys.activeMQ.username,
    passcode: keys.activeMQ.password,
    'heart-beat': '5000,5000',
  },
}
connManager = new stompit.ConnectFailover(
  [serverPrimary, serverFailover],
  reconnectOptions,
)
connManager.on('error', function (e) {
  const connectArgs = e.connectArgs
  const address = connectArgs.host + ':' + connectArgs.port
  logger.error({ error: e, customMessage: address })
})

    channelPool = new stompit.ChannelPool(connManager)
```

Code for sending message

```
const pushMessageToAMQ = (queue, message) => {
      const queues = Object.values(activeMQ.queues)
      if (!queues.includes(queue)) {
        _mqLog(mqLogMessages.unknownQueue + queue)
        return
      }
      //Priority header is set
      const header = {
        destination: queue,
        priority: 7
      }
      //If message is not a string
      if (typeof message !== 'string') message = JSON.stringify(message)
      //Logging message before sending
      _mqLog(
        mqLogMessages.sending,
        { service: services.amq },
        { header: header, message: message },
      )
      //Sending message to amq
      _sendMessageToAMQ(header, message, error => {
        if (error) {
          _mqError(error, mqLogMessages.sendingError, { service: services.amq })
        }
      })
    }

const _sendMessageToAMQ = (headers, body, callback) => {
      channelPool.channel((error, channel) => {
        if (error) {
          callback(error)
          return
        }
        channel.send(headers, body, callback)
      })
    }
```

Here's the code for subscribing to queue in the second application:

```
const amqSubscribe = (queue, callback, ack = 'client-individual') => {
  log({ customMessage: 'Subscribing to ' + queue })
  const queues = Object.values(activeMQ.queues)
  if (!queues.includes(queue)) {
    return
  }
  channelPool.channel((error, channel) => {
    let header = {
      destination: queue,
      ack: ack,
      'activemq.prefetchSize': 1,
    }
    //Check for error
    if (error) {
      _mqError(error, mqLogMessages.baseError, header)
    } else {
      channel.subscribe(
        header,
        _synchronisedHandler((error, message, next) => {
          //Check for error
          if (error) {
            _mqError(error, mqLogMessages.subscriptionError, header)
            next()
          } else {
            //Read message
            message.readString('utf-8', function (error, body) {
              if (error) {
                _mqError(error, mqLogMessages.readError, header)
                next()
              } else {
                //Message read successfully call callback
                callback(body, () => {
                  //Acknowledgment callback
                  channel.ack(message)
                  next()
                })
              }
            })
          }
        }),
      )
    }
  })
}
```

Activemq.xml

```
<policyEntries>
            <policyEntry queue=">" prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" expireMessagesPeriod="0" queuePrefetch="1" />
.......
```

I tried pushing different messages with different priority and turned on the second application (i.e. the one which subscribes to the messages) after all the messages were pushed to queue. However, the execution order of the messages was the same as the one which was sent. The priority didn't change anything. Is there something that I am missing?
Do I have to add something in consumer end for it to work?

Comment: What ActiveMQ backend do you have? And what priorities did you send?

Comment: I used priority 3 and 7 as values. I am locally using activemq 5.16.0. In production i will be using amazon MQ as the broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for priority is disabled by default in ActiveMQ "Classic" (used by Amazon MQ). As the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues) states:

> ...support [for message priority] is disabled by default so it needs to be be enabled using per destination policies through xml configuration...

You need to set `prioritizedMessages="true"` in the `policyEntry` for your queue, e.g.:

```xml
 <destinationPolicy>
  <policyMap>
    <policyEntries>
      <policyEntry queue=">" prioritizedMessages="true"/>
      ...
```

To be clear, this is configured on the *broker* (i.e. not the client) in `activemq.xml`, and it applies to **every** kind of client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin, I am using activeMq 5.16 locally as of now and I don't have any policyEntry for my queue as I am using activemq with stomp protocol in Nodejs, policyEntry is only  applicable for Java. According to what I have checked prioritizedMessages is true by default while using stomp protocol. Even though could you tell me how do I update the value of "prioritizedMessages" using stomp and nodejs. It would be of great help!

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have added "<policyEntries>
                <policyEntry queue=">" prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" expireMessagesPeriod="0" queuePrefetch="1" />", in my activemq.xml file. But still the messages are arriving in the order which I sent

Comment: What about when your consumer receives them? Are they ordered by priority in that case?

Comment: No @Justin, they are ordered in the same order I sent them. Priority is not making any diffference.
Is there something that I have to do after changing activemq.xml or is there some mistake in the change made to activemq.xml file

Comment: Did you restart the broker after making the changes to `activemq.xml`?

Comment: Yeah I did do that through brew, brew stop service activemq and brew start service activemq

Comment: Thanks. It was the issue of brew, it was not stopping the broker really, I restarted without using brew and it worked